# Assign an object to an element as an attribute in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I have this scenario where i need to assign a java-script object to div attribute.

```
var temp["name"]="first";
```

i assigned it to a div tag attribute using Jquery.

```
div.attr('data-polygon',temp);
Object [ <div#image01> ]
```

when i try to retrieve it , it does not come back same.. it is converted as String.

```
div.attr('data-polygon');
"[object Object]"
```

Any proper option / alternate to retain the object in attribute? please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are **always** strings.

Here are two options for doing this; since you're already using jQuery, the first is probably best:

#### jQuery's `data`

jQuery provides the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method for doing this:

```
// Setting -- notice no "data-" prefix
div.data("polygon", temp);

// Retrieving
varName = div.data("polygon");
```

Under the covers, traditionally `data` assigns the element a unique ID and manages a data cache for the element, separate from it. I think in the v3 branch they've updated it to actually store the data on the element (there were memory issues with doing that in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, which is why jQuery didn't do it before).

#### Assign it as your own "expando" property

If you don't need to support Internet Explorer 8, you can just create a property on the actual DOM element.

```
// Setting
rawDiv.myUniquePrefixToAvoidConflicts_polygon = temp;

// Getting
varName = rawDiv.myUniquePrefixToAvoidConflicts_polygon;
```

Note that to avoid conflicts with the many predefined properties elements have, and future ones they don't have *yet*, you'll want to use a likely-unique prefix.

Comment: Hi @t-j-crowder, i tried to load multiple data attributes to a div tag .. but only i can see the last loaded attribute.. others are empty value.. any idea ?

Comment: @jmanoj86: I can't help with that without seeing the code (ideally a runnable MCVE using Stack Snippest). But it would be a separate question.